# Making GridView with HtmlControls

Tags: asp.net, gridview, htmlcontrols

How can I create a GridView using data from the DataBase was

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
```

namespace and has the following features be?

like this code:

```
HtmlTable tbl=new HtmlTable();
```

1. pagination
2. sorting
3. editing field and row
4. and are selectively delete individual rows using CheckBox

Comment: use gridview with template fields.Why there is need to use `HtmlTable`

Comment: I don't want to use ASP.NET Default DataGridView control.I want to Generate DataGridView manually by HtmlControls